# How to disable copy and paste activity in ionic3 form fields

Tags: ionic3

Is it possible to remove copy and paste in ionic3 form fields?

I tried using the below CSS code but not working,(i.e the options are displaying, long press on input field )

```
 ion-input {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;    /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
    -webkit-user-select: none;      /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
    -ms-touch-callout: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -moz-touch-callout: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
```

Comment: try to add class name instead ion-input to apply this properties.

Comment: You could try by replacing the `ion-input` by `ion-input input` to target the input html element directly

Comment: @sebaferreras, I tried but not working..

Comment: Did someone able to solve this?